# Does filtering and protecting the ground with an inductor, capacitor, and TVS have a benefit?

Tags: noise, grounding, emi-filtering, shield

Let's assume a situation where you have a symmetrical power supply with the following output (in bracket is the net name, see the picture):

- +15V (+15V_DCIN)
- -15V (-15V_DCIN)
- GND (GND_DCIN)
- Earth (GND chassis, galvanically isolated)

Connected to a 3-pin LEMO connector with shielded a cable connected to a LEMO socket to a PCB in a metal enclosure.

As I learned from the pros, if you would like to make it really nice I should make a narrow GND chassis plane on the PCB and connect there a + and - voltage via filtering capacitor and protective TVS diode and make a bridge with an inductor or CM choke to the ground plane region where you make a + and - plane or whatever, like on this picture:

[image: Schematic]

My question is about the GND of the Lemo connector. If I would like to do it very correctly, should I filter this GND to GND chassis with capacitor and protect it with a TVS diode and separate it from PCB ground with inductor like it is on this schematic (like I do it for + and - voltage) or it is not necessary for GND?

I taking about very low-noise OPAMP which will be connected to 24bit ADC.